# How to unittest BaseHTTPRequestHandler subclass methods in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, http

Basically I have one `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` subclass with single `do_POST` method. I want write few unittest for it. Check how it process bodyless requests, for example. Maybe this closer to integration testing. But any way how I can do this?

Ideally I want something like

```
handler_instance = ...
self.assertRaises(myException, handler_instance.do_POST)
```

in test_method definition.